# Erro "'object' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments"

Tags: c#

Queria saber por que está acontecendo esse erro.

Eu criei uma classe que extende outra, mas quando chamo o construtor dela (classe pai) gera um erro.

Ali fala que não existe um construtor com 1 parâmetro, mas como podem ver na segunda imagem, existe sim.

[image: subclasse]

[image: superclasse]

Comment: Provavelmente a classe que você está tentando herdar não foi reconhecida... Tenta mudar o nome da classe que você está criando ou verifique se está faltando alguma referência ou inclusão do using dos namespaces usados.

Comment: Estaria aparecendo erro nela, e eu não conseguiria ver a  "definição" dela (Peek Definition), já importei tudo certinho.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No seu código:

```cs
class MySQLConnection : MySqlConnection
```

No código da superclasse:

```cs
public sealed class MySqlConnection : DbConnection, IDisposable, ICloneable
```

Basicamente, você não deveria herdar de `MySqlConnection`. Não há porque fazer isso e aquele `sealed` na declaração da classe diz que é proibido herdar dela.

Não sei o que você está tentando fazer, mas seja o que for, você não deveria tentar herdar de `MySqlConnection`.

Além disso, ter duas classes cujo nome só difere em maiúsculas/minúsculas é uma péssima prática de programação, pois é muito confuso.

Comment: Ah, claro, nem tinha percebido esse modificador lá, vlw.